# How to use a VNC source in Quartz Composer?

Tags: vnc, quartz-composer

I know I can use video camera sources for further processing with Quartz Composer. (For example you can use the iSight's video feed to do something with that.)

But is it also possible to show/use the source of a VNC server in Quartz Composer? Maybe there is some kind of a VNC Client plugin for Quartz Composer?

Comment: There is already a [VNC server for Quartz Composer](https://github.com/mirek/quartzcomposer-vnc) at least...

Answer (score 1):

I would try using [CamTwist](http://camtwiststudio.com/) as a go between, you can use VNC as a source in CamTwist, and CamTwist can then pose as a camera in QuartzComposer.

You can also use Quartz compositions as filters in CamTwist so you could go very meta.